# Recursive function to flatten multidimension array

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to flatten a multidimensional array into a one dimensional array using a recursive function.

My single dimension array `elements` is returning `undefined`

JS Bin with my example, [here](http://jsbin.com/woxebozudo/edit?html,js,console,output).

HTML:

```
<span class="one"></span>
<span class="one"></span>

<span class="two"></span>
```

JS:

```
// elements collection
var elementsCollection = [];
var elements = [];

/*  toSingle
*  convert mutlidimensional array to one dimensional array (i.e. flatten)
*
*  @param ec - array
*/
function toSingle (ec) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ec.length; i++) {
        if (ec[i].length) {
            toSingle(ec[i])
        }
        else {
            elements.push(ec[i]);
        }
    }
}

// get elements by their HTML class name
var buttons = [ 'one', 'two' ];

// collect elements from class names
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  elementsCollection.push(document.getElementsByClassName(buttons[i]));
}

// convert multiDimensional array to one dimensional
elements = toSingle(elementsCollection);

// log
console.log(elements);  // undefined
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: use [`querySelectorAll();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to receive a single object. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the array `elements`.

A recommendation is putting that array `elements` into the function `toSingle`

```js
/*  toSingle
 *  convert mutlidimensional array to one dimensional array (i.e. flatten)
 *
 *  @param ec - array
 */
function toSingle(ec) {
  var elements = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ec.length; i++) {
    if (ec[i].length) {
      elements = elements.concat(toSingle(ec[i]));
    } else {
      elements.push(ec[i]);
    }
  }

  return elements
}

// get integers, first, previous, next, last buttons by their HTML class name
var buttons = ['one', 'two'];

// elements collection
var elementsCollection = [];
// collect elements from class names
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  elementsCollection.push(document.getElementsByClassName(buttons[i]));
}

// convert multiDimensional array to one dimensional
var elements = toSingle(elementsCollection);

// log
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<span class="one"></span>
<span class="one"></span>
<span class="two"></span>
```

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger because the function `toSingle` returns an array, so I don't want to push an array, rather I want to concatenate the objects within that array.

Answer (score 0):

First point, you can use querySelectorAll() to avoid an useless loop (and pass an array as argument, as it will be coerced toString).

Second, if you don't mind using es6's features, just spread the received object in an array.
Only two lines left:

(also be aware that, although this doesn't seem to be the case in your example, with @Ele's solution, you have to remove duplicates in case you have elements having both or more classes)

```js
var buttons = ['.one', '.two','.three'];
var elements =[...document.querySelectorAll(buttons)];

console.log(elements);
```

```html
<span class="one two"></span>
<span class="one two three"></span>
<span class="two one four"></span>
<span class="one"></span>
<span class="two three"></span>
```